# Что означает typename = void? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, typename

Есть шаблон:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
```

Что означает 2 параметр? Если typename U = void я могу понять, как тип U, который по умолчанию равен void, то как понять просто typename = void?

Comment: Это безымянный параметр шаблона, для которого по-умолчанию должен использоваться тип `void`. Видимо кто-то решил сэкономить на байтах.

Comment: @user7860670 но какой смысл указывать значение по умолчанию для параметра без имени? Мы же не сможем к нему доступ без имени получить. Разве что только для перегрузок и SFINAE это может быть нужно?

Comment: Почему, можем. Помимо сценариев с перегрузками с SFINAE, еще возможны варианты со специализацией и с предварительным объявлением.